# how to use mongoimport to import a json file

Tags: json, mongodb, database

I'm trying to import a json file using `mongoimport` with this command line:

```
mongoimport --db posts --collection rows --file post_history.json
```

but it returns this error:

```
connected to: localhost
Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character 'N' after object key:value pair
imported 0 documents
```

The content of the file looks like this:

```
[
 {
 "Id" : 1,
 "PostHistoryTypeId" : 2,
 "PostId" : 1,
 "RevisionGUID" : "1e04af17-3bdb-4263-aa46-97ee7fb1b0b6",
 "CreationDate" : "2011-06-21 20:19:34",
 "UserId" : 9,
 "Text" : "My finance and myself are looking for a good Caribbean cruise in October and were wondering which islands are best to see and which Cruise line to take?"
 },
 {
 "Id" : 2,
 "PostHistoryTypeId" : 1,
 "PostId" : 1,
 "RevisionGUID" : "1e04af17-3bdb-4263-aa46-97ee7fb1b0b6",
 "CreationDate" : "2011-06-21 20:19:34",
 "UserId" : 9,
 "Text" : "What's the best Caribbean cruise for October"
 },
 {
 "Id" : 3,
 "PostHistoryTypeId" : 3,
 "PostId" : 1,
 "RevisionGUID" : "1e04af17-3bdb-4263-aa46-97ee7fb1b0b6",
 "CreationDate" : "2011-06-21 20:19:34",
 "UserId" : 9,
 "Text" : "<caribbean><cruising><vacation>"
 },
 {
 "Id" : 4,
 "PostHistoryTypeId" : 2,
 "PostId" : 2,
 "RevisionGUID" : "58500a29-b9ed-4802-9934-c173ce362758",
 "CreationDate" : "2011-06-21 20:22:33",
 "UserId" : 13,
 "Text" : "This was one of our definition questions, but also one that interests me personally: How can I find a guide that will take me safely through the Amazon jungle? I'd love to explore the Amazon but would not attempt it without a guide, at least not the first time. And I'd prefer a guide that wasn't going to ambush me or anything :P"
 },
 {
 "Id" : 5,
 "PostHistoryTypeId" : 1,
 "PostId" : 2,
 "RevisionGUID" : "58500a29-b9ed-4802-9934-c173ce362758",
 "CreationDate" : "2011-06-21 20:22:33",
 "UserId" : 13,
 "Text" : "How can I find a guide that will take me safely through the Amazon jungle?"
 }
]
```

What am I missing? Is it the right command? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**:
As CodeBird suggested I've tried this command:

```
mongoimport --db posts --collection rows --type json --file post_history.json --jsonArray
```

it returns this:

```
connected to: localhost
Failed: error processing document #18875: invalid character 'N' after object key:value pair
imported 10000 documents
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use this command to tell mongo it is a json array

```
mongoimport --db posts --collection rows --file post_history.json --jsonArray
```

I copied your json, and tested:

```
mongoimport --db posts --collection rows --file test.json --jsonArray
2016-01-19T06:18:57.887-0600    connected to: localhost
2016-01-19T06:18:57.906-0600    imported 5 documents
```

**EDIT**

Following your question update, I think you might also have some special characters that should be fixed for mongo for example:

```
tab = \t
" = \"
\ = \\
```

Comment: @DamianFox, there should be some unaccepted characters in your json file like for example a tab which should be `\t` or `"` which should be escaped like this `\"` or a \ which also should be escaped like this \\ etc....