# Adding a thousand-lined-data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So I have an JSON file with around couple thousand lines: in the following format:

```
[ {name: "a", description: "1"}, ... {name: "a", description: "1"}]
```

I tried using

```
db.a.insert([{name: "a", description: "1"}, ... {name: "a", description: "1"}])
```

but I guess terminal has a character limit and only was able to insert the first couple lines.

Is there a better way to insert big amount of data on to MongoDB other than having to repeat this line of code couple hundred times?

Comment: Try : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#examples

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use mongoimport to import a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876544/how-to-use-mongoimport-to-import-a-json-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you have a local database without authentication

`mongoimport --db DATABASE_NAME --collection COLLECTION_NAME --drop --file FILE_NAME.json`